# Storage Address of Smart Contract Variables

Tags: contract-deployment, evm, storage

I need to know storage address of solidity smart contract variables before its deployment. how can I get this?

Answer (score 1):

Which storage slots are allocated for which contract variable depends on the language and/or compiler. The Solidity compiler has an option to output the storage layout as a JSON structure:

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/internals/layout_in_storage.html#json-output

In the Solidity language you can use `.slot` in assembly to get the storage slot of a variable:

```
pragma solidity 0.7.4;

contract StorageSlotFetch
{
    struct ThreeSlots
    {
        uint256 a;
        uint256 b;
        uint256 c;
    }
    address var0;
    uint256 var1;
    bytes32 var2;
    ThreeSlots var3;
    uint256 var4;
    
    function getStorageSlots() external pure returns (uint256[5] memory ret)
    {
        assembly {
            mstore(add(ret,   0), var0.slot)
            mstore(add(ret,  32), var1.slot)
            mstore(add(ret,  64), var2.slot)
            mstore(add(ret,  96), var3.slot)
            mstore(add(ret, 128), var4.slot)
        }
    }
}
```